# Search kit list display broken

Tags: civicrm-home, searchkit

My Search kit list display does not show a list of searches anymore.

[image]

The console says the following:
[image]

I am using civicrm 5.40 drupal 7.82
Anyone has a clue on where to start solving this?

Comment: Do you have any blank / broken entries in the civicrm_group table? I had a similar error that was caused by a group with no name/title.

Answer (score 1):

I checked and that function definitely does exist. The first things I would try are:

1. Ensure you are using the search_kit extension in core (in the `civicrm/ext/search_kit` directory). Delete any others e.g. in your site's extension directory, or in `civicrm/ext/search` which is the old path before the extension was renamed).
2. Clear all caches.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Andrew for helping me in the right direction. I found a roque saved search that had no connection to a group. I deleted it and the searchkit list display workes again.