# Search kit broken and templates not parsed

Tags: searchkit, angular

I have 1 local environment, 1 dev, 1 staging and 1 prod.

Everything is fine on local and dev, but on staging and prod, the SearchKit page looks like that:

[image: Screenshot of the broken SearchKit page displaying Twig]

The console says:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: savedSearchesProvider <- savedSearches <- searchList
https://errors.angularjs.org/1.8.2/$injector/unpr?p0=savedSearchesProvider%20%3C-%20savedSearches%20%3C-%20searchList
    Angular 39
    jQuery 2
    <anonymous> Angular
    jQuery 7
    <anonymous> Common.js:1606
    jQuery 8
 <div ng-view="" class="ng-scope">
```

I tried to cleanup groups and saved searches, as suggested in [Search kit list display broken](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/40125/search-kit-list-display-broken) with no results.

I've cleaned-up the cache to.

Why am I stuck like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found out!

The call was made by **searchList.controller.js** which is automatically loaded from *civicrm/ext/search_kit/ang/crmSearchAdmin/*

But this file has been removed in CiviCRM 5.42 and its deletion was omitted in one of my upgrades.

just cleaned-up the directory:

```
rm civicrm/ext/search_kit/ang/crmSearchAdmin/searchList.*
```

and everything goes fine.